# Return Index List from Dynamic Linq Query

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I've got a filter method which takes a generic array of structs, executes a query and/or orderby and/or take expressions as strings using dynamic linq, and returns a list of matching indexes, which is then used by an external program.

I initially adopted a bit of a rough and ready approach to getting the index list, simply by iterating over the original list and finding where the item was equal to an item in the filtered list, as follows:

```
    public static int[] FilterStructs<T>(IList<T> structs, string query = "", string orderBy = "", int topN = 0) where T : struct {            
        var filteredStructs = structs.AsQueryable();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query)) filteredStructs = filteredStructs.Where(query);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy)) filteredStructs = filteredStructs.OrderBy(orderBy);
        if (topN > 0) filteredStructs = filteredStructs.Take(topN);
        return GetArrayIndexList(structs, filteredStructs.ToArray());
    }

    private static int[] GetArrayIndexList<T>(IList<T> arrMain, T[] arrFiltered) where T : struct {
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrFiltered.Length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrMain.Count; j++) {
                if (arrMain[j].Equals(arrFiltered[i])) {
                    indexes.Add(j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return indexes.ToArray();
    }
```

However, when the array of structs has even a few thousand items in it, this becomes hideously slow.

What I'd ideally like to do, is initially use a dynamic select statement to project the array of structs into a new array with an additional "index" field, perform the filtering, and then returning only these index values from a select statement would be trivial.

However, I'm drawing a bit of a blank as to how this could be accomplished.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simpler than I thought, although this isn't my ideal solution, because I have to alter every incoming string expression for the query and orderby clauses to include the projected entity name. It works though, so it will do for now until I have more time.

```
    public static int[] FilterStructs<T>(IList<T> structs, string query = "", string orderBy = "", int topN = 0) where T : struct {
        var withIndex = structs.Select((s, i) => new { index = i, item = s });
        var filteredStructs = withIndex.AsQueryable();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query)) filteredStructs = filteredStructs.Where(query);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy)) filteredStructs = filteredStructs.OrderBy(orderBy);
        if (topN > 0) filteredStructs = filteredStructs.Take(topN);
        return filteredStructs.Select("index").Cast<int>().ToArray();            
    }
```

For instance, if my previous where clause was "value = 123", it now has to become "item.value = 123".

Comment: Incidentally, this has reduced execution time from using the GetArrayIndexList method from around 1500ms down to 40ms.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the filtered array elements are guaranteed to exist in the original array so you might replace the GetArrayIndexList body with the following.

```
 private static int[] GetArrayIndexList<T>(IList<T> arrMain, T[] arrFiltered) where T : struct
    {
        return arrFiltered.Select(c=> arrMain.IndexOf(c)).ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I think IndexOf will use the default equality comparer, which is what was causing the method to be slow. Although this is much less code, it's still taking well over 1 second for an array with 4000 items.